# Maven Error: Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong version

Tags: java, maven, hudson, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to release a project with a custom plug-in dependency. And maven throws an error saying,

> > [INFO] [INFO] Internal error in the
> >     plugin manager getting plugin
> >     'com.xxx.xxx.tools:generate-xxx-config':
> >     Plugin
> >     'com.xxx.xxx.tools:generate-xxx-config:0.0.1'
> >     has an invalid descriptor: [INFO] 1)
> >     Plugin's descriptor contains the wrong
> >     version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have not seen this error before. I am guessing it means that the version tag in the pom.xml of the custom plugin does not match. Does it end with -SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This is what I found. I was using maven version 2.2.1. I changed it to 2.0.11 and it worked.

Cannot fathom why it did not work with 2.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

Inside plugin jar there is a plugin.xml file that contains the plugin version. From 2.2 Maven validates  that value from file matches the one from pom and directory structure.